# Use pyspark to run a custom defined function from python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, custom-function

I wrote a custom function that will find the most word occurrences from a .txt file.  I need to run it through PySpark as an RDD

I wrote a function called top_five whos only parameter is file_name

```
import collections

def top_five(file_name):    

    file = open(file_name, 'r', encoding = 'utf8')

    list1 = []
    for line in file:
        print(line)
        words = line.split()
        for i in words:
            j =''.join(filter(str.isalpha, i))
            j = j.lower()
            if len(j) > 5:
                list1.append(j)            

    count = collections.Counter(list1)

    most_occur = count.most_common(5)

    print("The most used words in the Applied Data Science Textbook is:")
    for item in most_occur:
        print("\t" + item[0] + " occured " + str(item[1]) + " times")

    return
```

The actual results need to be the last 3 lines of the top_five function where its prints each word and the number of occurences

Answer (score 1):

Where possible, you should use Spark APIs entirely rather than trying to wrap an existing function that depends on loops and local state to a specific executor (from using a dictionary counter)

```
file_name = 'README.md'

spark = SparkSession.builder\
  .master('local[*]')\
  .getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext

rdd = sc.textFile(file_name)\
  .flatMap(lambda x: x.lower().split())\  # lowercase and split lines
  .map(lambda word: ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, word)))\  # remove non-alpha characters from words
  .filter(lambda word: len(word) > 5)\  # filter short words
  .map(lambda word: (word, 1))\  # count each words
  .reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b)\  # sum the counts by word
  .sortBy(lambda t: t[1], False)  # sort the words by descending counts

# Collect to a Python list
top_words = rdd.take(5)
for word_pair in top_words:
    print(f'"{word_pair[0]}" occurred {word_pair[1]} times')
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear which of the above objects is associated with the PySpark Dataframe that you would ideally be augmenting here.

Convert your function into a [PySpark UDF](https://changhsinlee.com/pyspark-udf/), which will allow you to apply your logic to a PySpark Dataframe without having to convert to Pandas and back.

For very large dataframes, it is commonly known that UDFs can perform very poorly / take a long time to run. This is also my personal experience.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to use a UDF just to do word count plus a sort

Comment: @cricket_007 - I agree there are better ways to execute the above. Per your point [here](https://www.tutorialkart.com/apache-spark/python-spark-shell-pyspark-example/) is a perfectly good example of a word count performed in PySpark. I was directly responding to OP's original question. Not reframing the question.